# How do i calculate the sum of the price with quantity input fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an invoice form in a table. I want to calculate the total of each item when you add the quantity in the field.I have items listed with the quantity blank but has the amount of the item. I want to get the total only when i add a quantity to the field.Currently i have been able to calculate the total without the quantity.
   Kindly use this link  [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/2zvwc5k9/)

```
               <table width="82%" class='table borderless'>

      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td width="15%">Saddle (75mm x 3/4) : </td>
        <td width="11%">

          <input type="text" name="num" id="num">             </td>
        <td ><input   onFocus="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty" value="55"/></td>
      </tr> <tr>
        <td width="15%">Ferrule (19mm) : </td>
        <td width="11%">

          <input type="text" name="num" id="num">             </td>
        <td ><input   onFocus="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty" value="60"/></td>
      </tr> <tr>
        <td width="15%">HDPE Pipe (25mm) : </td>
        <td width="11%">

          <input type="text" name="num" id="num">             </td>
        <td ><input   onFocus="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty" value="4.5"/></td>
      </tr> <tr>
        <td width="15%">Stopcock (19mm) : </td>
        <td width="11%">

          <input type="text" name="num" id="num">             </td>
        <td ><input   onFocus="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty" value="45"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
     <button type="submit" name="process" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit Estimate</button> 







function findTotal(){
        var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
        var tot=0;
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
                tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
        }
        document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling `findTotal ` you need to call `findTotal` every time an input changes, the form is send or the button is clicked.

Comment: You haven't described what exact problem you are having. All you said is what your end goal is. You have to tell us what is wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Please br more spesific about what you want and what you have tried so far. First of all, what `findTotal()` function does right now is sum the all the numbers in column `amount`. Which is probably wrong. And i can only assume that you need to multiply every row among each other and then calculate the result. Your workaround right now is messy and your instructions are not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will add display the total of quantities*amounts in the readonly input field marked "Total". Note: generally `class` should be used for multiple elements, `id` should be unique for each element. If you want the amount to also be a readonly field just add the keyword `readonly` immediately after the defined value. I used `onBlur` instead of `onFocus` to allow the user to edit the values before they change.

```js
function findTotal(){
        var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
        var scale = document.getElementsByName('num');
        var tot = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i].value != "" && scale[i].value != ""){
                tot += parseInt(scale[i].value) * parseInt(arr[i].value);
            
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}
```

```html
<table width="82%" class='table borderless'>

      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td width="15%">Saddle (75mm x 3/4) : </td>
        <td width="11%">

          <input value = 0 type="text" onBlur="findTotal()" name="num">             </td>
        <td ><input   onBlur()="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" value="55"/></td>
      </tr> <tr>
        <td width="15%">Ferrule (19mm) : </td>
        <td width="11%">

          <input value = 0 type="text" onBlur="findTotal()" name="num">             </td>
        <td ><input   onBlur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" value="60"/></td>
      </tr> <tr>
        <td width="15%">HDPE Pipe (25mm) : </td>
        <td width="11%">

          <input value = 0 type="text" onBlur="findTotal()" name="num">             </td>
        <td ><input   onBlur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" value="4.5"/></td>
      </tr> <tr>
        <td width="15%">Stopcock (19mm) : </td>
        <td width="11%">

          <input type="text" name="num" value = 0 onBlur="findTotal()">             </td>
        <td ><input   onBlur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" value="45"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Total: </td>
          <td><input type="text" id='total' value=""readonly></input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
     <button type="submit" name="process" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" onclick="findTotal()">Submit Estimate</button>
```